# sharepoint 2013 client svc processquery check if it's loaded

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

sharepoint 2013 client svc processquery(client.svc/ProcessQuery) check if its loaded

I have this search webpart that return the result in client svc processquery check.

How can I check/monitor when this client svc processquery  is loaded via javascript?